# how to prevent imageView from extending under navigationBar in ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

Please help with this issue.
I have a viewcontroller with two container views, each one pointing to a separate viewcontroller.

The first viewcontroller is supposed to show an image but the top portion is getting cut off by the navigation bar.

I have unchecked "Extend under Top Edges".

my viewcontrollers for the two container views are pretty much empty.

Any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var teamMember:TeamMember!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let name = teamMember.firstName {
        title = name
    }
    navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "PictureViewController") {
        var destination = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        var vc = destination?.topViewController as? PictureViewController
        vc?.teamMember = teamMember
    }

    if (segue.identifier == "BioContentViewController") {
        var vc = segue.destination as? BioContentViewController
        vc?.teamMember = teamMember
    }
}
```

edit: I am also setting custom nav bar items, i don't know if that causes an issue

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "PictureViewController") {

        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "Meet The Team"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "teamMemberDetailView") {

        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "Meet The Team"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

        var vc = segue.destination as? TeamMemberDetailViewController
        vc?.teamMember = teamArray[selectedTeamMemberIndex]
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard]

Comment: What constraints are you using on your `UIImageView`?  Is it tied to the `topLayoutGuide`?

Comment: In `viewDidAppear` could you print the frames of the missing views. It would help to debug the issue

Comment: @ScottThompson no constraints..

Comment: @ScottThompson ok i added constraint: UIimageView to top layout guide, of size = 0.. but no difference

Comment: one way i got it semi-working was to set top space to top layout guide = 100

Answer (score 0):

Tie the imageView to Top Layout Guide.

[image]

In case you want your image to come over the navigation bar, you can add it to UIWindow.

Comment: i think i set this ?  but no but no difference
http://imgur.com/a/5VGId

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInset to `false` for the view controllers.

I think this [blog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/) will help you working with container view controllers.